# Connecting to Localhost on Mac from Another Mac: Websocket Issues?

Tags: node.js, macos, websocket, localhost, wifi

I have a node.js web app running on http://localhost:3000/ on my **iMac**. I am able to log on to that web app from Chrome on my **MacBook** using the Wi-Fi IP address of my iMac (found in System Preferences->Network) and the port my web app is running on:

> http://10.0.0.37:3000

When using this technique, is there any reason why a websocket would fail in calling a service on a distant server?

Thanks in advance to any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out nothing was wrong with websockets. The camera on my MacBook was deactivated for some reason, and that was causing errors from the service I was accessing. I was able to reactivate the camera using instructions [from this page](http://macdrug.com/there-is-no-connected-camera-error-on-macbook-fix/):

> Quit all apps that you are trying to use with the Camera > Open
>   Terminal (find in /Applications/Utilities) > copy and paste the
>   following command then hit the Enter key > Type administrator password
>   hit Enter.
>
> sudo killall VDCAssistant
>
> if still at the terminal, issue the following command:
>
> sudo killall AppleCameraAssistant